# Arduino Project Needs Print Statements to Work

Tags: c++, serial-port, arduino, led

I have this Arduino code I want to run that listens for input coming in via serial from some c++ code I'm writing. This information is being written to the connection, but I see some really strange behavior on the Arduino side.

If I don't put the print statements in (specifically the non printRGB() statements), I don't see any output to the Serial Console. As soon as I add them in they start to appear again. What's going on?

```
#define LED_PIN 13
#define R_PIN 3
#define G_PIN 5
#define B_PIN 6
#define frameBegin ((char) 255)

char colors[] = {
  0,0,0};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(R_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(G_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(B_PIN, OUTPUT);
  //  establishContact();
  Serial.println("blah");
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char inByte = Serial.read();
    toggleLED();
    // Got a new frame
    //Serial.println('S');
    if (inByte == frameBegin) {
      //Serial.println('B');
      //write bass
      boolean allThree = true;
      for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        char rgb = Serial.read();
        if (rgb == frameBegin) {
          //Serial.println('F');
          allThree = false;
          break;
        }
        else {
          colors[i] = rgb;
        }
      }
      if (allThree) {
        //printRGB();
        analogWrite(R_PIN, colors[0]);
        analogWrite(G_PIN, colors[1]);
        analogWrite(B_PIN, colors[2]);
      }
    }
  }
}

void printRGB() {
  Serial.print("rgb: ");
  Serial.print((uint8_t) colors[0]);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print((uint8_t) colors[1]);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println((uint8_t) colors[2]);
}
```

Comment: if you don't print anithing to the serial, what are you expected to read?
your own command will not appear as they are not written by the arduino, and serial monitor does not care to give you a log of what you had written.

Comment: See printRGB(). It's called after I get a particular byte signifying the beginning of a "frame" and I get the number of values I expected.

Comment: And if you remove it you won't see anything because it is never called. I can't understand whats wrong with that. Why you expect to read something on the SerialConsole removing the code that write that values on the serial?

Comment: Woops, sorry! Pasted the code before pulling it from the repo :D.
Updating now- look at serial.println("b") serial.println("s") etc. Leaving the printRGB() in at all times, without the println("B"/"S") the RGB values never print.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit weird, because timing and conversion.
First of all: you wait for ONE byte readed, put in "inByte".
We know Serial.read() cannot return -1 because we are sure there is at least one byte.
VERY IMPORTANT: note that -1 in int, coverted to byte (uint8_t) is 255 (also your (char)255 means -1, see 2's complement to understand why)

then you do some code, with is really fast, but you can uncomment the Serial.print() witch will slow it down.

then you read 3 byte without being sure that 3 byte have been recived; with serial.print() you added a delay with, lucily, let you read this byte, BUT witout print() your code is so fast (9600 baud rate means 960byte/s!! this is really slow) that no byte is arrived and you alwayr get a -1 from Serial.read (witch means "nothing to read") and you convert it to char (still -1), but then print it as (uint8_t), and so it usigned and has value of 255.

tested on my arduino uno, IDE 1.5.4